# how to call and work with HTTP Request and Receive data from (API) to Odoo?

Tags: json, httprequest, odoo

I have an external system and I need to use its API in an odoo 12 system

This system give me Excel file and I want to convert this file to CSV file or import its data in odoo database

Comment: You can refer this link for basic of API : https://www.odoo.com/documentation/12.0/webservices/odoo.html

Answer (score 0):

you can call external api through compute in models by importing requests
ex.
import requests
class(models.Model):
     temperature = fields.Char(compute='_get_temperature')

```
def _get_temperature(self):
    res = requests.get('http://externalapi.com')
    for result in self:
        result.temperature = res
```